# How can I keep a selenium webdriver alive?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to write a selenium test in python, where i would need to start a selenium webdriver and keep that driver alive so it can be called in other functions (defs) to get webpages.

I'm trying to do this in order to considerably reduce execution time.

Any suggestions / insights would be highly appreciated thank you all.

**UPDATE**

The following is a piece of sample code to illustrate what I am trying to achieve. Ideally I would like chromedriver to stay open between the two function calls to avoid having to tear it down and restart chromedriver which takes a lot of time, if you have multiple (50+) function calls.

```
def chromedriver_function(url):    
    # Start Webdriver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path="/opt/chromedriver")

    driver.get(url)

    return driver.page_source

def function1()
    ... do something
    chromedriver_function("http://www.example.com")

def function2()
    ... do something
    chromedriver_function("http://www.mysecondpage.com")
```

Comment: You want to keep the browser open after you program ends? Post a sample of your code.

Comment: @Jordan yes thats what I'm trying to do, precisely I would like to keep it open between function calls. I have updated the question with some sample code to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Just create the driver and return its value. Then call your function using this value as parameter

```
def create_driver():
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path="/opt/chromedriver")
        return driver

def chromedriver_function(driver,url):    
    # Do whatever you want here

    driver.get(url)

    return driver.page_source

def function1(driver)
    ... do something
    chromedriver_function("http://www.example.com")

def function2(driver)
    ... do something
    chromedriver_function("http://www.mysecondpage.com")
```

And call your functions like this

```
driver = create_driver()
function1(driver)
function2(driver)
```